# Pos Tagger in PHP

Tags: php, pos-tagger

I am looking for a pos-tagger which can be used in php.Or i need to know if there is any way to use results of Qtag java app with php.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP/IR](http://phpir.com/part-of-speech-tagging) has an article on "Part Of Speech Tagging" with an implementation of a Brill Tagger

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at PHP wrapper of Standford NLP processor. This is a more complete implementation of the functionality then the PHP/IR.

https://github.com/agentile/PHP-Stanford-NLP

The git hub page has examples to get you started fast.